# What should I learn/know before reading Investments by Bodie Kane Marcus?

Tags: self-study, investment, books

I hope this is the appropriate place to post this. If not, I would really appreciate if someone could redirect me to the right site.

I've been seeing a lot of recommendations for the book, Investments by Bodie Kane Marcus, and was wondering what sort of educational background I would need to understand the contents of this book.t I'm currently a first-year computer science undergrad and have done single variable calculus with some rigor. Is there other stuff I should get myself acquainted with before diving in, or does the book assume nothing and will teach whatever concepts it uses itself?

Comment: It is an introductory text so hopefully you won’t need much background knowledge. Best way would be to start reading the text, make notes of the contents you don’t understand, and when you reach the end of a chapter then look up the terms you have noted. Sorry if it sounds patronising

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I did a quick skim of the book and saw usage of things like covariance and other topics from statistics, does the book introduce these things as it goes or am I expected to know these topics beforehand?

Comment: Not too many unexplained concepts, so won’t say you need to read a full statistics book before starting this book, though you definitely should read more about statistics!

Comment: In my  edition of BKM there is an Appendix A called Quantitative Review where he goes over basic Probability and Statistics concepts used in the book. As the title indicates it would probably be better if you had already some exposure to these concepts and just used the Appendix for review.

Comment: That sounds great, which edition do you have?

Comment: It is an early edition (second), get a newer one.